# Ajax form, 2 drop downs with external source

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, jquery

is there a way once I select from a drop down list on a form that it will select all models from the first dropdown in a second drop down

Here is my code

```
        <form>
            <div class="landing_quote_left">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="0">
                    <tr>
<td>
                            <label for="ajax_make_id" class="landing_quote_label">Make:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span id="ajax_make_select"><select name="2f_make_id" id="ajax_make_id" style="width: 170px;" onchange="Landing.getMakeFace(this.value);"><option value="999">Select a Make</option><option value="1">Acura</option><option value="2">Audi</option</select></span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="ajax_model_id" class="landing_quote_label">Model:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span id="ajax_model_select">

                                <select name="2f_model_id" id="ajax_model_id" style="width: 170px;" onchange="Landing.getModelFace(this.value);">
                                    <option value="">Loading...</option>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- END landing_quote_left -->
        </form>
```

So if I select Acura, the second drop down will show a list of all models ie 
MDX
RDX
RL
TL
TSX
ZDX

If possible, how would I have both dropdowns load from different files. {php or xml or whatever else is possible}

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some rough code on how to accomplish this.

On page load, populate dropdown1.

```
$(function(){
    $.get('file1.php', function(data){
       $('#dropdown1').html( data ); 
    });

    // on change of dropdown1 populate dropdown2 with the respective data 
    $('#dropdown1').change(function(){
        $.get('file2.php',{ make: $(this).val() }, function(data){
            $('#dropdown2').html( data ); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

So in your file2.php you can check the `$_GET` array for the `make` variable passed in, then you can send back all the options for that model. You could also send back json instead of html but this gives you a rough idea of how to do it and i think it's best to keep it simple at first.

Comment: I'm sorry being newbish with this but how would I go about implementing this?
I add the above script to my index.php file with <?php ?> tags and then I get lost what to do next. I'm really trying to learn if you can help out. I appreciate it!